# Universal formula to calculate the number of days in a month taking into account leap years

Tags: calendar

Does someone know a math formula to calculate the number of days in a month like this one

```
28 + (x + Math.floor(x/8)) % 2 + 2 % x + 2 * Math.floor(1/x);
```

but which also takes in to account leap years? It should also take into account that the Gregorian calendar omits 3 leap days every 400 years, which is the length of its leap cycle.

Comment: What range of years?  How many of the idiosyncrasies of the world's calendrical systems do you need to take into account?  1584, 1752, 1712, ... any of those of significance to you? (If you were in Sweden in 1712, then February had 30 days; does your formula need to account for that?)

Comment: You are right. Personally I need formula from 1900 till 2100. But it would be nice to get something more universal without taking into account Sweden (still it is very interesting information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't very hard to add a term `(m == 2) * leapyear(yyyy)` to the expression to determine the correct number of days in February of a leap year.  This C code shows a way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static inline bool leapyear(int yy)
{
    if (yy %   4 != 0) return false;
    if (yy % 100 != 0) return true;
    if (yy % 400 != 0) return false;
    return true;
}

static inline int old_dim(int mm)
{
    return (28 + (mm + (mm/8)) % 2 + 2 % mm + 2 * (1/mm));
}

static inline int new_dim(int mm, int yyyy)
{
    return (28 + (mm + (mm/8)) % 2 + 2 % mm + 2 * (1/mm) + ((mm == 2) * leapyear(yyyy)));
}

int main(void)
{
    /*28 + (x + Math.floor(x/8)) % 2 + 2 % x + 2 * Math.floor(1/x);*/
    for (int mm = 1; mm <= 12; mm++)
        printf("mm = %2d, DIM = %2d\n", mm, old_dim(mm));

    for (int yyyy = 1900; yyyy < 2101; yyyy += 5)
    {
        for (int mm = 1; mm <= 12; mm++)
            printf("yyyy = %4d, mm = %2d: DIM = %2d\n", yyyy, mm, new_dim(mm, yyyy));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output for `mm = 2` (filtered from the full output) is:

```
yyyy = 1900, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1905, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1910, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1915, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1920, mm =  2: DIM = 29
yyyy = 1925, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1930, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1935, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1940, mm =  2: DIM = 29
yyyy = 1945, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1950, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1955, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1960, mm =  2: DIM = 29
yyyy = 1965, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1970, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1975, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1980, mm =  2: DIM = 29
yyyy = 1985, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1990, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1995, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2000, mm =  2: DIM = 29
yyyy = 2005, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2010, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2015, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2020, mm =  2: DIM = 29
yyyy = 2025, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2030, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2035, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2040, mm =  2: DIM = 29
yyyy = 2045, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2050, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2055, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2060, mm =  2: DIM = 29
yyyy = 2065, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2070, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2075, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2080, mm =  2: DIM = 29
yyyy = 2085, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2090, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2095, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 2100, mm =  2: DIM = 28
```

This correctly considers 1900 and 2100 as non-leap years, but 2000 as a leap year.

```
yyyy = 1900, mm =  1: DIM = 31
yyyy = 1900, mm =  2: DIM = 28
yyyy = 1900, mm =  3: DIM = 31
yyyy = 1900, mm =  4: DIM = 30
yyyy = 1900, mm =  5: DIM = 31
yyyy = 1900, mm =  6: DIM = 30
yyyy = 1900, mm =  7: DIM = 31
yyyy = 1900, mm =  8: DIM = 31
yyyy = 1900, mm =  9: DIM = 30
yyyy = 1900, mm = 10: DIM = 31
yyyy = 1900, mm = 11: DIM = 30
yyyy = 1900, mm = 12: DIM = 31

…

yyyy = 2000, mm =  1: DIM = 31
yyyy = 2000, mm =  2: DIM = 29
yyyy = 2000, mm =  3: DIM = 31
yyyy = 2000, mm =  4: DIM = 30
yyyy = 2000, mm =  5: DIM = 31
yyyy = 2000, mm =  6: DIM = 30
yyyy = 2000, mm =  7: DIM = 31
yyyy = 2000, mm =  8: DIM = 31
yyyy = 2000, mm =  9: DIM = 30
yyyy = 2000, mm = 10: DIM = 31
yyyy = 2000, mm = 11: DIM = 30
yyyy = 2000, mm = 12: DIM = 31
```

Answer (score 0):

simplify that formula, skip the hard-coded constants, and eliminate extra temp variables beyond the 2 input values :

(*ensure they're being passed-by-**value** not by-reference*)

```
function month2numdays(__, _) {

    # __| month-# [1-12]
    #  _| (opt.) leap flag - numerically non-zero or string
    #      beginning w/ "L" of either case are treated as TRUE 

    return \
    (_ = (_ = !!+_ || _ ~ "^[Ll]") + _ == (__ = int(__))) + \
    (_+= (_^= _) + _)^_ + _^(__ != --_) + (__ + (_*_*_ <= __)) % _
}
```

`^` is ***exponentiation*** not bit-wise XOR

---

```
1  ____  31   2  ____  28   3  ____  31   4  ____  30
5  ____  31   6  ____  30   7  ____  31   8  ____  31
9  ____  30  10  ____  31  11  ____  30  12  ____  31

1  Leap  31   2  Leap  29   3  Leap  31   4  Leap  30
5  Leap  31   6  Leap  30   7  Leap  31   8  Leap  31
9  Leap  30  10  Leap  31  11  Leap  30  12  Leap  31
```

---

The unified approach leverages `30 := 3 + (27 := 3^3)`, and the `0-th power` (i.e. boolean condition evaluated as **FALSE**) of anything is `1`, eliminating subtractions and trimming it down to just 1 `modulo %` operation